# Cookies and iframes, how to deal with them?

Tags: cookies, iframe, security

The other day I discovered that iexplorer is not accepting cookies from an iframe unless the iframe provides P3P authorization. At first, I was like "WTF?", but today I was wondering about the bad things that could happen.

For example, I have a website named `herp.com`, where you can delete a product with `http://herp.com/product/111/delete` (I know this is a bad practice, `GET` should be indepotent). Then a malicious webmaster creates a web in `http://derp.com` with an iframe to `http://herp.com/product/111/delete`, so... if I, as logged user in `herp.com`, open `derp.com` with my browser... will I delete the product 111?

Which more issues should I be afraid of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more afraid of your http GET causing a delete.  The scenario you are describing is not much different than throwing a redirect on a page from derp.com to herp.com/product/111/delete.  In either scenario, the user will unknowingly load herp.com, and the browser will automatically supply any cookies for that site.

Comment: You're right, it's such a bad design that doesn't worth it considere it. Cheers.